# Unable to select rows from the last 7 days

Tags: mysql, datetime

I created the table yesterday and all should be selected however the query is returning only the rows added yesterday (20) but none from today.

This is my table structure:

```
Followed | Follower | Date (DATETIME)
```

This is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM Follows 
WHERE Date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY `Followed`
```

is there a way to select all rows post 7 days ago instead of limiting them to CURDATE()? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why do you need to `GROUP BY`? Maybe that is the reason. You can post a db_dump so we can check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to cast the DATETIME attribute to a DATE to compare with the CURDATE():

```
SELECT * FROM Follows 
WHERE cast(Date as DATE) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY `Followed`
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
WHERE Date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND CURDATE()
```